# Is it possible with Jenkins to run a batch file locally

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

So rather then running the batch file on a specified node, I need the batch file to run on the same machine that I have Jenkins logged into. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the job configuration, `General` section, select the check box

> Restrict where this project can be run

then set the field

> Label expression

to `master`

Comment: Locally as in the workstation im logged into to access Jenkins, which in this case is not the master.